# How do I save an html form post to two databases? Rabbitmq vs Redis pub/sub?

Tags: flask, redis, rabbitmq, amazon-dynamodb, python-asyncio

I have a Flask microservice that needs to save a form post to both AWS DynamoDB (thru boto3) and to Elastic Search DB (running on EC2). I first considered writing a Python AsyncIO server to implement a broker/Observer pattern but it looked like re-inventing what Rabbitmq/Redis PubSub already does. However, I couldn't find straight forward documentation (both doc sites) and therefore, I am looking for an example of this common pattern. Any pointers would be helpful and I will appreciate your help.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are using AWS already, so why not use [SNS](https://aws.amazon.com/sns/). You can create a `form_post_topic` with two subscribers (DynamoDB and ElasticSearch) and you send messages to that topic.